# Constant lower bound of this summation involving factorial?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial, upper-lower-bounds

Given

$$f(n)=\frac{n}{(2 n) !} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left((n+i-1) ! \sum_{k=0}^{i} \frac{(n-k-1) !}{(i-k) !}\right)$$

where $n$ is natural.

Is there a constant lower bound for $f(n)$, i.e., is there a constant $c>0$ such that $f(n)\ge c$ for each natural $n$?

This complicated formula basically means some probability, and I (strongly) believe that it can be lower bounded by a constant since I've calculate several points via [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=f%5C%2840%29n%5C%2841%29%20%3D%20Divide%5Bn%2C%5C%2840%292n%5C%2841%29%21%5D%20Sum%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29n%2Bi-1%5C%2841%29%21Sum%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29n-k-1%5C%2841%29%21%2C%5C%2840%29i-k%5C%2841%29%21%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Ci%7D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bi%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D%20where%20n%20%3D%20200):

| n | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 15 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f(n) | 0.5 | 0.4167 | 0.3917 | 0.3798 | 0.3710 | 0.3550 | 0.3529 | 0.3508 | 0.3497 | 0.3478 | 0.3472 | 0.3470 | 0.3469 |

But I have no idea what math tools or techniques can be used to lower bound $f(n)$. Can anyone give a (tight) constant lower bound or prove that $f(n)$ has no constant lower bound?  Thanks in advance!

**UPDATES:**

If we only consider the term where $i=n-1$ in the summation, a lower bound of $1/4$ can be easily obtained:

\begin{align}
f(n) &\ge \frac{n}{(2 n) !}\cdot (n+i-1) ! \cdot\sum_{k=0}^{i} \frac{(n-k-1) !}{(i-k) !} \\
&= \frac{n^2\cdot(2n-2)!}{(2n)!} \\
&\ge 1/4
\end{align}
Then the question is: can we get a bound larger than $1/4$?

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

We can compute the inner sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^i\frac{(n-k-1)!}{(i-k)!}=\frac{n !}{i! \,(n-i)}$$ and this makes
$$f_n=\frac{n \,n!}{(2 n)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(i+n-1)!}{i! \,(n-i)}$$ I did not find any expression for the remaining summation and, as you did, I computed the value for $n=10^k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & f_{10^k} &f_{10^k}-f_{10^{k-1}} \\
 1 & 0.3593857 &  \\
 2 & 0.3478267 & -0.011559 \\
 3 & 0.3466986 & -0.001128 \\
 4 & 0.3465861 & -0.000113
\end{array}
\right)$$
It *seems* that is slowly converging.

Comment: Thanks, Leibovici! This could provide some insight.  Do you think the Stirling's formula will help?

Comment: @MengfanMa. The summand in my writing is a monster. I tried also special functions and nothing came. I am still working it. If anything new, I shall post. Cheers :-)

Comment: It seems that in your simplified summation, only the term where $i=n-1$ is $\Theta(1/4)$, other terms with $i<n-1$ is $o(1)$, thus $1/4$ is indeed the tight bound.